# How can I convert non-asciis to numbers in php?

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii

I just started to code in php, and I got a task to do.
I have to read non-ascii characters like the " character from a file, convert them to a string array,  the convert into integers,and add numbers to them.

For example, if I have the '"' character, I should get 147, then if I add -31 to it, it should return the character 't'.

Here is a code i tried;

```
    $file = fopen("word.txt", "r") or die("File missing");
    $wholefile=fread($file, filesize("word.txt"));
    fclose($file);
    
    $words =explode(chr(0x0A), $wholefile);

      $file = fopen("password.txt", "r") or die("File missing");
    $wholefile=fread($file, filesize("password.txt"));
    fclose($file);
    
    $words =explode(chr(0x0A), $wholefile);

    //An exmaple
    $str = $words[0];
    for($i = 0; $i< strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $str[$i] = chr(ord($str[$i]) - 31);
    }
    echo "$str";
```

```
Can you help me to get ascii characters isntead of ��-s?

The content of the file (exmaple)
pS“`nf2†ddn^MZrrŠ
```

Comment: BTW, `"` is still ASCII. It's just a *punctuation character*.

Comment: @deceze, when interpreting a byte stream as Windows 1250/1252, code points 147 and 148 correspond to "smart quotes" that some systems/fonts interpret as `"`, which is what I think the OP is going for. To the OP, you need to determine if you are in "legacy mode" or modern. If you are in the former, you are going to be living in the world of code pages which was a nightmare, and the safest thing is to build a static lookup table based on your specific dataset. If you are in the modern world, everything is UTF-8 and what you are doing doesn't really make sense. Why are you subtracting `31`?

Comment: These words are "decoded password", and the encode function is substracting integers from the password's characters. The result will be always an ASCII character. And the ord() function did not work here. Instead of 147 I get 226. (I think, the probem is the character encoding, because it caused many problems in my similar C project.) I need some function/ method/algorythm, that returns the right value of the character.

Comment: You do know that you are overwriting `$words` in your second block, right? Maybe that's just a copy-and-paste thing. I have a vague idea of what you are trying. I'd recommend using a function such as `unpack` to get the string as a byte array and print that out for debugging. `var_export(unpack('C*', 'hello world'));`

Comment: After some debugging, I realized, that  characters higher than 128 are converted into three numbers like (226 128 156). So 226 128 156  represents the “ character. Can you help me to get the extended ASCII code of this character?